# Angular - Date picker toggle is not visible before clicking

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I am trying to add date picker in Angular8.

I have code like below

> ```
> <mat-form-field>
>   <input matInput [matDatepicker]="myDatePicker"/>
>   <mat-datepicker-toggle [for]="myDatePicker" matSuffix></mat-datepicker-toggle>
>   <mat-datepicker #myDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
> </mat-form-field>
> ```

I have imported like below in app.module.ts

> import { MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule, MatFormFieldModule,
> MatInputModule  } from '@angular/material';

I have added all four in @NgModule import

When page is loaded, Any element is not visible but showing up when I click on it

[image: When Page loaded]

[image: Clicking Input]

[image: Clicking Toggle]

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Check the console if you are getting an errors

Comment: @NicholasK No error is showing in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could solve the issue. I was missing the style import. I did import like below in style.css of main folder.

> `@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';`

It was not mentioned in tutorials but I realized when I downloaded working example and compared with my code.